# How can you add a class in CSS to animate it on the page?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to animate two images from the centre, the the opposite sides of each other.

One to the far left, and the other to the far right, with some text in the middle.

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zgLz6fh/3/)

I have seen on a few websites now an `is-visible` css attribute (for example, something like this):

```
.image.is-visible {
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.image {
    background-position: right;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(45%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(45%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(45%);
    -o-transform: translateX(45%);
    transform: translateX(45%);
```

I have my `transform: translateY(0%);` on my jsFiddle, but how do you add a class, for example: `is-visible` to animate it on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Class is probably done by a jQuery

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

So you just need to define when the class should be added

Maybe while scrolling
Example:

http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/zvGQZN

Or if the document is loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".someclass").addClass("is-visible");
});
```